# Why the __del__destructor information was showed twice here in my python program?

Tags: python

My code is like this.(python 2.7 Ubuntu)

```
class Garbage:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __del__(self):
        print "Something in Garbage is destoryed"
    def test(self):
        print "I'm exist"

item1= Garbage()
item2= Garbage()
print id(item1)
del item1        
item2.test()
```

But the result shows like this:

```
3074861408
Something in Garbage is destoryed
I'm exist
Something in Garbage is destoryed
```

---

Why there the "Something in Garbage is destoryed" is showed twice? I only deleted item1,
but not item2.

Comment: It might be more obvious what's going on if you change the `__del__` method to `print id(), " Garbage is destroyed"` and the `__init__` method to `print id(), " Garbage is created"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the Python interpreter exits, the destructors of any remaining objects may or may not be called as part of the shutdown sequence. In this case, `item2` happened to be destructed.

Note that the `del` operator doesn't call its operand's `__del__` method. The garbage collection system calls that once it determines that an object is no longer reachable. In CPython, that usually happens immediately once the object is unreachable, but it might be delayed, or it might never even happen if the interpreter never decides it's time for a collection.

Comment: This last sentence is a bit confusing for novices, maybe even misleading. The CPython interpreter never waits for a collection to destroy things, it always does so as soon as the object's refcount goes to 0. The only thing a collection ever does is to find and break reference cycles (so that objects that are only reachable from each other can be deleted).

Comment: @abarnert: "The CPython interpreter never waits for a collection to destroy things" - It waits for a collection to destroy anything kept alive by a reference cycle.

Comment: If you read the entire comment instead of just the first fragment, the very next bit of it says "The only thing a collection ever does is to find and break reference cycles (so that objects that are only reachable from each other can be deleted)."

Comment: I think you might be using a different definition of the word "reachable". Objects that are only reachable from each other aren't reachable. CPython only immediately collects unreachable objects with refcount 0; it has to wait for a collection to collect unreachable objects kept alive by a reference cycle.

Comment: My point is that the way you've written it is confusing or even misleading _for novices_, not that it's technically indefensible. I understand your explanation, but someone who didn't already know about the reference cycle detector would likely draw the wrong inference from it.

Answer (score 1):

`item2` is being destructed also when the script finishes, as noted in other answers. You can verify this easily:

```
class Garbage:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __del__(self):
        print self.name, "Garbage is destroyed"

    def test(self):
        print self.name, "exists"

item1 = Garbage("item1")
item2 = Garbage("item2")
print id(item1)
del item1        
item2.test()
```

Produces:

```
python test.py
42948288
item1 Garbage is destroyed
item2 exists
item2 Garbage is destroyed
```

Answer (score -1):

When a variable goes out of scope, it is destroyed. In this case, it's when the program ends.

Comment: Values get destroyed, not variables. And they get destroyed when the interpreter notices that there are no references to them. When variables go out of scope (or are `del`'d), that indirectly means one less reference to the value, but it doesn't directly destroy anything. And the program ending isn't guaranteed to release any references left over in `__main__`'s globals, either.